# how pass Employee object in restFul Get method

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

I am passing an Employee Object Form Client in RestFul webservices Jaxrs2/jersy2

```
 @GET
    @Path("{empObj}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response readPK(@PathParam("empObj")Employee empObj) {
        //do Some Work
        System.out.println(empObj.getName());
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(result).build();
    }
```

how can achive this object using GET method??
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

By using `@PathParam` on a method parameter / class field you're basically telling JAX-RS runtime to inject path segment (usually string) to your (String) parameter. If you're sending an object (Employee) representation directly via your URI (query param, path param) you should also provide [ParamConverterProvider](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/ParamConverterProvider.html). Beware that this is not possible in some situation and it's not a recommended practice. However, if you're sending the object from client to server in message body, simply remove `@PathParam` and [MessageBodyReader](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) will take care of converting input stream to your type:

```
@GET
@Path("{empObj}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response readPK(Employee empObj) {
    //do Some Work
    System.out.println(empObj.getName());
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(result).build();
}
```